# How to switch SceneKit views by utilizing different classes

Tags: ios, scenekit, swift-playground

I have three sceneKit views that I would like the users to see. This is a Xcode Playground and so I do not have a storyboard or else this would have been quite simple. I need to change the liveView of the Playground as a certain boolean becomes true or false.

I have tried to use if statements to check whether the two booleans were either false or true and then change my liveView according to them but the issue is that the code to setup the liveView only runs once meaning that it will always stick to the view that was first assigned.

```
    physics = false
    lit = true
    if(lit == true)
    {
        let vc = LitController()
        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: 812) //iPhone X
        PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc

    }
    else if(physics == true)
    {
        let vc = PhysicsController()
        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: 812) //iPhone X
        PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc

    } else
    {

        let vc = MyViewController()
        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: 812) //iPhone X
        PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
    }
```

I would like this to constantly run so that I can switch views whenever necessary, is this possible? If not what is something else that I can do to execute what I would like?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise placing this within the `didSet` of the physics variable. Another possible way would be to wrap your existing code in a function and make another function that changes the variable. The second function should, when called, call the first function. This makes sure this code runs whenever you explicitly change the variable. However, I would strongly recommend using `didSet` for this purpose as it runs *every time* the variable is changed.
Here are a few examples if you’re confused.

```
class ExampleClass {
    var boolean : Bool {
        switchViews()
    }
    func switchViews(){
        //Code here
    }
}
```

Whenever `boolean` changes value, `switchViews()` is called. The next example uses the two functions method.

```
var boolean:Bool = true
func changeBoolean(_ to:Bool){
    boolean = to
    switchViews()
}
func switchViews(){
    //Code here
}
//Changes boolean value and calls switchViews()
changeBoolean(false)
```

This is, as mentioned, another way. I would recommend the first. Hope this helps, and let me know if they above code contains bugs or doesn’t work.

Comment: Another thing, you should use `switch` instead of `else if`

Comment: Hi @Ritz Beast if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.